# How to SetActiveWindow from external process?

Tags: windows, c++

I've been looking for a way to make a window active but some odd reason the MSDN says that the function will only succeed if the window is within the caller thread process. I have no idea why they would do this very frustrating.

I am just looking for a way to make a window active. If you don't know what I'm talking about here is what I mean:

[image]

Things I've tried:

`SetActiveWindow(TargetHwnd);`

`PostMessage(TargetHwnd, WM_SETFOCUS, 0 ,0);`

`SendMessage(TargetHwnd, WM_SETFOCUS, 0, 0);`

`SetForeGroundWindow(TargetHwnd);`

Is there really no easy way to do this? I really don't understand why this is even challenging.

Alternatives that I think would work but just don't want to do because overkill:
Set mouse pos on window and just simply send a input that mouse down mouse up (simulate clicking the window???)
Maybe simulate keyboard alt tab???
Inject DLL to set active window, but I don't want to do this one.

This is for usermode API but if there is a kernel equivalent API I will be more than happy to hear it.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know

Comment: Hi, this isn't a reverse engineering question, I'm afraid.

Comment: its to avoid confusing the user.

Comment: So is there no way to set the active window of a external window?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow

Comment: That is function does not set the active window, you can test this yourself.